# запись тестового файла в БД sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.5, sqlite3

Как в БД sqlite3 записать тестовый файл, а потом его оттуда сохранить так, как он и был (python 3.5)

```
import sys
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect("test.db")
cur = con.cursor()  # Загрузка файла в БД

file_input = open("test.txt", "r")
file = file_input.read()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES (?)", file,)
con.commit()  # Выгрузка файла из БД
cur.execute("SELECT file FROM files LIMIT 1")
data = cur.fetchone()[0]

file_output = open("test.txt","w")
file_output.write(data)
file_output.close()

con.close()
```

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "F:\file_db_test\test_db.py", line 11, in <module>  cur.execute("INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES (?)", file,) sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: files –`

Comment: Точно так же как и любые другие данные: insert, select, вот это вот всё

Comment: import sqlite3 as lite  
import sys  

con = lite.connect("test.db")  
cur = con.cursor()  

#Загрузка файла в БД  
file_input = open("test.txt", "r")  
file = file_input.read()  

cur.execute("INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES (?)", file,)  
con.commit()  

#Выгрузка файла из БД  
cur.execute("SELECT file FROM files LIMIT 1")  
data = cur.fetchone()[0]  
file_output = open("test.txt","w")  
file_output.write(data)  
file_output.close()  
con.close()

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\file_db_test\test_db.py", line 11, in <module>
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES (?)", file,)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: files

Comment: create table не забываем

Comment: @user040617 вставьте, пожалуйста, этот код в вопрос.
в python критически важны отступы, а тут их не видно.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sqlite3
import sys
  
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()
  
# Загрузка файла в БД
file_input = open('blank.pdf', 'rb')
file = file_input.read()
file_input.close()
binary = sqlite3.Binary(file)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO files(file) VALUES (?)', (binary,) )
con.commit()
  
# Выгрузка файла из БД
cur.execute("SELECT file FROM files LIMIT 1")
data = cur.fetchone()[0]
file_output = open('blank2.pdf', 'wb')
file_output.write(data)
file_output.close()
con.close()
```